# Full image html in website

Tags: html, css

I want to ask. How can i make full image for the header like the image in html? could someone please give me some reference about creating that thing? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Just add height: 100%;width: 100%; as style

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this, if you want the background to be fixed.

```
body { 
background-image: url('w3css.gif');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`background-size: cover` might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
.class{ 
background-image: url('img/background.jpg') no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size:cover;
height: 100vh;
}
```